# what could be possible reasons for integrationMBeanExporter ... javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websphere, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have chose to implement my jobs using Spring Batch Admin and, unfortunately, it works perfectly in all environment except the production. I guess there is another application from another team causing some indirect effect but I can't stop them in order to check which one is affecting and if there is really some application affect.

I am desparetely looking for possible causes and I can't find. Any imagine reason would be a start point appreciatted.

The entire error is:

```
Trace: 2016/09/09 22:49:17.049 02 t=9BDE88 c=UNK key=P8 tag= (13007004)

  SourceId: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.logServletError

  ExtendedMessage: BBOO0220E: SRVE0293E: ÝServlet Error¨-ÝBatch Servlet¨: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: E

rror creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.export.U

nableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean Ýorg.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter@4ed60bcf¨

with key 'integrationMBeanExporter'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: spring.application:cell=dt

l85cel,name=integrationMBeanExporter,type=IntegrationMBeanExporter,node=wlemyAppa,process=WLEmyApp

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.j

ava:1553)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.jav

a:539)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:

475)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:70

3)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:7

60)

...

at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanSe

at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:814)

at com.ibm.ws390.management.connector.corba.CorbaConnectorImpl.invoke(CorbaCon

at com.ibm.ws390.management.connector.corba._CorbaConnectorImplBase._invoke(_C

at com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.invoke(CommonBridge.java:1898)

at com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.getAndProcessWork(CommonBridge.java:725)

at com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.runApplicationThread(CommonBridge.java:614)

at com.ibm.ws390.management.connector.corba.CorbaConnectorImpl.invoke(CorbaCon

at com.ibm.ws390.management.connector.corba._CorbaConnectorImplBase._invoke(_C

at com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.invoke(CommonBridge.java:1898)

at com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.getAndProcessWork(CommonBridge.java:725)

at com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.runApplicationThread(CommonBridge.java:614)

at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$ZOSWorker.run(ThreadPool.java:2116)

Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean Ýorg.springframework.integration.

monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter@4ed60bcf¨ with key 'integrationMBeanExporter';nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlready

ExistsException: spring.application:cell=mycel,name=integrationMBeanExporter,type=IntegrationMBeanExporter,node=wlemyAppa,process
```

Is there any way to turn off in Spring Batch Admin such duplicated Bean? How can I try IGNORE_EXISTING or REPLACE_EXISTING just to see if it fix my problem?